# access to servlet return HTTP status 404

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with my web application. I made my application using netbeans with glassfish as a default web server. Whenever I compile and deploy my program to localhost, it works fine but when I try to deploy it on a remote web server which has an apache tomcat 7.xx version, it returns a http status 404 error whenever the program access a servlet. I checked the servlet mapping and everything seems to be ok. Here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mainservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.MainServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mainservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mainservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How are you deploying the application to tomcat web server? is it through the tomcat manager site or by copying the file under the webapps folder?

Comment: Is the Tomcat server behind Apache, as is commonly the case? If so, it it Apache or Tomcat that's returning the 404?

Comment: I'm copying the file under the webapps folder. actually I am using mocha web hosting and I just followed the instruction on how to deploy. I'm using the probe application if you're familiar with that.